# Datagridview comportamiento extraño columnas autogeneradas + una columna manual

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una tabla con esta información

```
UUID                                    Fecha CFDI                  RFC             Cliente             Folio   Serie   Total           Saldo pendiente Estatus_cfdi
A3CA0DE7-6981-43D5-AED1-4D4056466F12    2019-08-15 10:17:45.000     XAXX010101XXX   DUMMY CLIENT 1      24179           876.500000      876.500000          1
02A95486-790B-46BB-A9A6-B227462C05E7    2019-08-15 08:55:49.000     XAXX010101XXX   DUMMY CLIENT 2      24178           1500.000000     1500.000000         0
0DBCF18F-536E-411C-A7B0-5D0FE30CDFF5    2019-08-14 18:42:06.000     XAXX010101XXX   DUMMY CLIENT 3      24177           812.000000      0.000000            1
```

Con la que lleno un datagridview, vía datasource. Una vez hecho esto, creo manualmente una columna extra con un checkbox.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn doWork = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
            {
                HeaderText = "Pagar"
            };
            dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, doWork);
```

Tengo un método que se encarga de cambiar el color de la fila dependiendo del valor de la columna 'Estatus_cfdi'

```
private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[8].Value) == 0)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
```

El comportamiento "extraño" se da al colorear las filas: en lugar de colorear las filas que tienen 0 en 'Estatus_cfdi' colorea las que tienen 0 en 'Saldo Pendiente'. Si borro la columna generada manualmente funciona correctamente. ¿Alguien podría explicarme qué estoy haciendo mal?

Ya intenté con todos los índices de la columna, y el comportamiento es el mismo en todos los casos que permiten la evaluación de la condición (campos string mandan error) y si intento utilizar lo que sería la última columna (índice 9) marca error de índice fuera del intervalo (es la columna generada manualmente).

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres aplicar color a las filas del grid en base a una condicion usa el evento `CellFormatting`

Entonces tu codigo seria algo como

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Estatus_cfdi"))
    {
        var row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        int intValue;
        if (Int32.TryParse((String)e.Value, out intValue) && 
            (intValue == 0))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

La idea es que puedas evaluar la columna por su `Name`

[How to: Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-data-formatting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Leandro Tuttini! Había intentado con CellFormatting, pero no me funciona correctamente, me daba un error de índice fuera del intervalo usándolo en un foreach, después leí que CellFormatting tiene graves problemas de rendimiento porque se ejecuta con cada columna de cada fila. De todos modos, probé tu código y me marca error `System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Int16' al tipo 'System.String'.'` en la línea `if (Int32.TryParse((string)e.Value, out int intValue) && (intValue == 0))`

Comment: Ya lo corregí, pero no entiendo: si la condición la hago así: `if (int.TryParse((e.Value).ToString(), out int intValue) && (intValue == 0))` marca error de null reference exception (`e` viene con null), pero si hago `var i =Convert.ToInt32(e.Value).ToString(); if (int.TryParse(i, out int intValue) && (intValue == 0))` funciona correctamente.

Comment: si el campo es null quizas debas validarlo `if (e.Value != DBNull.Value && int.TryParse((e.Value).ToString(), out int intValue) && (intValue == 0))`, porque ese fallo se genera al realizar el ToString()